# How to modify user datas inserted in sharedpreference before it's saved?

Tags: android-preferences, preferences, preference

I would like to know if there is a simple way to modify a user data inserted in sharepreference before it's saved.

To be clear, I insert a code in my settings (preference), and I would like to crypt that code (for more security) then save it in sharepreference. When I read the preferences, I can decrypt that code, it's easy, but how to crypt it before preferences save it ?

I have several ideas :
1. make my own preferences and save it in a file or data base, but I would prefer to use sharepreference,
2. when exiting preferences (back key), read code inserted, crypt it, then save it, but lot of actions !

I'm looking for a better solution directly when I insert the code.

If you have a solution, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is the second one.

- create a new class (crypted_code) with a layout containing the editText box to read the code,
- adding a public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) to detect back key,
- then save the code after crypting it :

  ```
          code = crypt(code);
          SharedPreferences mgr = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mgr.edit();
          editor.putString("code", code);
          editor.apply();
          finish();
  ```